# after jquery shake effect (Display:none) why?

Tags: jquery, css, shake

for a projekt i want to have a shake effect for a image.

HTML

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 sales"><img title="product" alt="product" src="layout/icommerce/img/sale6.png" /></div>
```

jquery

```
$(".sales img").toggle("shake", {direction: "left",times: 4,distance: 1}, "slow");
```

after loading the page, the img is shaking, but at the end of the effect, the img goes to `display:none` by using `style="display:none"`

I don´t want that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you use `toggle()`. Use [`effect(...)`](http://jqueryui.com/effect/) instead:

```
$(".sales img").effect("shake", {
     direction: "left",
     times: 4,
     distance: 1
}, "slow");
```

From the jQuery UI documentation:

> ### [`Toggle`](http://jqueryui.com/toggle/)
>
> Display or hide elements using custom effects.

So, because your element was visible, after toggling it it becomes invisible (`display: none`).

Answer (score 1):

so add a callback parameter

```
$(".sales img").toggle("shake", {direction: "left",times: 4,distance: 1}, "slow",function(){
  $(this).css("display","block");
});
```

or setup whatever you like

Comment: this is like moving from New York to Washington DC going through London and Paris first.

Comment: yes, but if you do not have .effect() method how will you do that then if not like that?

Comment: if you're using jquery you have the effect() method. I didn't say your solution is wrong, just needlessy complicated.